# Dict of dict url encoded params for post request in Python?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, discourse

```
params_for_update_cat = {
    'api_key': API_KEY,
    'api_username':"ausername",
    "name": name_and_ticker,
    "color": bg_colour,
    "text_color": text_color,

    "permission": {'admins': 1,'staff': 2}
}


headers = {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}

r = rq.post(url=create_cat_url, data=params, headers=headers)
```

So what I want is and the above certainly doesn't do this:

```
  permissions[admin]=1&permissions[staff]=2
```

as parts of the params list. this should be in the post body of course.

Some caveats:

- The api doesn't support content-type: application/json request headers.
- The api is expecting the request to be made as data was coming from a form.

If I were to do this in curl and this is successfully test btw - it would be:

```
!curl -X POST "http://<mydomaingoeshere>/categories.json" /

-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" /

-F "api_key=xxxxxxxxx_xxxxx" /
-F "api_username=ausername" /
-F "name=checkcheckcheck" /
-F "text_color=FFFFFF" /
-F "color=49d9e9" /
-F "permissions[admins]=1" /
-F "permissions[staff]=2"
```

3 days on this - and no one has been able to help. Maybe something like this is a bad idea?  I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

How about being explicit in the dictionary:

```
params_for_update_cat = {
    'api_key': API_KEY,
    'api_username':"ausername",
    "name": name_and_ticker,
    "color": bg_colour,
    "text_color": text_color,
    "permissions[admins]": 1,
    "permissions[staff]": 2
}
```

This creates a request with the URL looking like:

```
"http://example.com?...&permissions%5Badmins%5D=1&permissions%5Bstaff%5D=2"
```